# capturing audio using libusb in Android

Tags: android, audio, usb, audio-recording, libusb

I am working on a SBC flashed with Android Kitkat version. (Board does have USB host). But since official usb audio native support was introduced after 5.0 in Android, I can't directly use USB audio device with SBC.
I am using libusb to serve the purpose. I am able to open particular endpoint. However getting all null data when captured. I don't get any errors in libusb calls.

Below is short pseudocode of steps followed:

```
libusb_init(NULL)
devId = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VID, PID)
if(libusb_kernel_driver_active(devId, IFACE_NUM)->detachKernel)
libusb_claim_interface(devId, IFACE_NUM)
libusb_set_interface_alt_setting(devId, IFACE_NUM, ALT_SETTING)
Loop{libusb_alloc_transfer(numOfPackets)
libusb_fill_iso_transfer(callBack)
libusb_set_iso_packet_lengths
libusb_submit_transfer}:NumOfTransfer(10) times
Inside callback: uint8_t* data = libusb_get_iso_packet_buffer_simple()
```

When I am trying to print buffer pointed by data all data is coming NULL. When checked my libusb_transfer struct elements in callback it gives Length of Buffer as 1960 but **actual Length is 0.**

I am using Logitech C310 webcam which has mic and act as USB audio device.
I am using Interface number 3 and alternate setting 4 as it is clear from below part of device descriptor

```
    Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x04    bDescriptorType
0x03    bInterfaceNumber
0x04    bAlternateSetting
0x01    bNumEndPoints
0x01    bInterfaceClass   (Audio Device Class)
0x02    bInterfaceSubClass   (Audio Streaming Interface)
0x00    bInterfaceProtocol   
0x00    iInterface

AS Interface Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x07    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x01    bDescriptorSubtype
0x03    bTerminalLink
0x01    bDelay
0x0001  wFormatTag   (PCM)

AS Format Type 1 Descriptor:
------------------------------
0x0B    bLength
0x24    bDescriptorType
0x02    bDescriptorSubtype
0x01    bFormatType   (FORMAT_TYPE_1)
0x01    bNrChannels   (1 Channels)
0x02    bSubframeSize
0x10    bBitResolution   (16 Bits/sample)
0x01    bSamFreqType   (Discrete sampling frequencies)
0x00BB80    tSamFreq(1)   (48000 Hz)

Endpoint Descriptor (Audio/MIDI):
------------------------------
0x09    bLength
0x05    bDescriptorType
0x86    bEndpointAddress   (IN Endpoint)
0x05    bmAttributes    (Transfer: Isochronous / Synch: Asynchronous / Usage: Data)
0x00C4  wMaxPacketSize   (196 Bytes)
0x01    bInterval
0x00    bRefresh
0x00    bSynchAddress
```

I am not getting where its going wrong? Can anybody share any working reference for usb audio on Android lower versions?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to get USB mic working on Kitkat. 
For those who are struggling with USB audio on android Kitkat version, below is short description of what I followed:
I took reference  from code [usbaudio-android-demo](https://github.com/shenki/usbaudio-android-demo)

This code is written for a specific device ie. TI's PCM2900C and has capture and playback using same device. To get it work for your USB audio device you need to modify VID, PID, MAX packet size, Interface number and correct alternate setting number with valid endpoint able to provide sufficient bandwidth. Once you are able to capture and playback audio, you need to adjust packet length, number of packets in buffer etc. to get clear audio.

But now I am having another issue. My application is not about recording audio and capture and playback USB audio, I need to use this raw PCM data as source for MIC in telephony application. Only thing I can think of solution now is passing this data to native audio code by modifying `device/vendor/sub-vendor/hardware/audio/audio_hw.c`. Is this correct approach or any better solution to this?